# Render elements from a template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I have a lot of elements but no idea of how to render them but to write 40 lines of jsx

```
<p>{this.props.data.list[0].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[1].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[2].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[3].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[4].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[5].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[6].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[7].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[8].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[9].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[10].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[11].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[12].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[13].dt_txt}</p>
<p>{this.props.data.list[14].dt_txt}</p>
```

and so on...

so how could i create a template to render them all with less mess?

Comment: Why not just map over `data.list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed arbitrary JavaScript **expressions** in your JSX, so for your example, it should look like this

```
... // Other markups
{ 
    this.props.data.list.map(item => {
        return <p key={item.dt_txt}>{item.dt_txt}</p>
    });
}
... // Other markups
```

Note that you must wrap your expression in `{}` within your JSX, or else, it will be rendered like plain text.

To learn more about why you need to specify a `key` like above, you can refer to this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the items in the list.
The react docs explain this pretty well https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

```
this.props.data.list.map((listItem) =>
  <p key={listItem.id}>{listItem.dt_text}</p>
);
```